# Как присвоить значение переменной js через php ?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Вопрос, с помощью пхп скрипта формирую некую массив переменную, скажем $a[0]="1.jpg";$a[1]="test.gif",.....$a[200]="finish.bmp";.Так,вот как можно эту переменную передать в js скрипту, например так сработаеть ли?

```
<?php
...............................
print ("<script>
var massiv =".$a." 
</script>");
..............................
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для подобных задач в основном используется json:

```
<?
$a[0]="1.jpg";$a[1]="test.gif";$a[200]="finish.bmp";
?>
<script>
var j = <?=json_encode($a)?>;
alert(j[0]);//выведет первый элемент массива "1.jpg"
</script>
```

**upd:**

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
$.post('get_img.php',function(a){
alert(a[0]);
},'json');
</script>
//**get_img.php:
<?
echo json_encode($a);
```

**JS:**

```
<script src="get_img.php" type="text/javascript">
//**get_img.php:
var a=<?=json_encode($a)?>;
alert(a[0]);
```

Comment: в браузере вижу 
<script>
var j=["1.jpeg","879.jpeg","56.jpeg","2.jpeg","3.jpeg"];
alert(j[0]);
</script>. Хотелось бы ,чтобы значения были скрытыми, то есть ["1.jpeg","879.jpeg","56.jpeg","2.jpeg","3.jpeg"] от пользователей, или как то можно их записать в другой файлик, и инклудить <script src>-oм?

Comment: Никак вы их не скроете, разве что шифровать будете (это тоже обходиться)

Comment: от просто пользователей можно через ajax, можно и через скрипты, но файлы всё равно будет видно.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, tsya.ru

Comment: @zavtramen - во первых русский не мой основной язык, во вторых мы не на форуме лингвистов