# Как передать ассоциативный массив из php в javascript

Tags: php, javascript, база-данных

Помогите срочно кто сталкивался с этим. Проблема заключается в следующем:
Не могу понять, почему но в цикле `while` из массива php передаются только 2 записи из бд, хотя их там 5!!! Самое интересное, передаются только первая и последние, а все остальные почему-то пропадают.

Вот кусок кода:

```
<html>  
<head>   
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
var TextArea = ["msgField1","msgField2","msgField3","msgField4","msgField5"];  
var Ip = ["ip1","ip2","ip3","ip4","ip5"];  
var GuestName = ["gnum1","gnum2","gnum3","gnum4","gnum5"];  
var DateL = new Array("date1","date2","date3","date4","date5");  
var Nav = new Array("D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9");  
var IdNav = new Array("F","S","T","FR","FF","SX","SV","E","N");  
var Comments = new Array();  
var IP_Addr = new Array();  
var Guest_Num = new Array();  
var i=0;  
</script>  
<?php  
$link = mysql_connect('xxxxxxxxx','xxxxxx','xxxxx');  
if (!$link) {  
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
}  
if (!mysql_select_db('xxx', $link)) {  
    echo 'Could not select database';  
    exit;  
}   
    $newSql = "SELECT * FROM Blog";  
    $newResult = mysql_query($newSql,$link);  
    if(!$newResult)  
    {  
       echo "DB Error 2 Level, could not query the database\n";  
       echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();  
       exit;  
    }else{   
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($newResult)) { //здесь возникает   логическая, возможно дело в счетчике но как его лучше организовать? Где обьявить?  
?>  
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">          
Comments[i] = "<?php echo $row['Comments'];?>";  
IP_Addr[i] = "<?php echo $row['IP_Addr'];?>";  
Guest_Num[i] = "<?php echo $row['Guest_Num'];?>";  
i++;  
</script>  
<?php   
            }  
         }  
    mysql_free_result($newResult);  
?>  
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
function showData(){  
        for(var j=0;j<=Comments.length-1;j++){  
        document.write(Comments[j] + "  " + IP_Addr[j] + "  " + Guest_Num[j] + i + "<br>");  
    }  
}
```

В результате получаю всего 2 записи из 5 (первую и последнюю).

Comment: @evgen84142009, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

@evgen84142009, [путь к истине](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/96905/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-js-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-php)

**UPd:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
Comments = "<?= json_encode($row['Comments']);?>";
IP_Addr = "<?= json_encode($row['IP_Addr'];?>";
Guest_Num = "<?= json_encode($row['Guest_Num']);?>";
  </script>
```

PS. проверьте массив vаr_dump($row) или print_r($row), чтоб увидеть элементы массива.

Comment: Vfvtnjd, спс за быстрый ответ. Я так понял ты предложил заменить конструкцию "<?php echo $row['Comments'];?>" на "<?=$row['Comments'];?>" -????Сделал так но все равно результат тот же(((

Comment: Comments = "<?= json_encode($row['Comments']);?>";
IP_Addr = "<?= json_encode($row['IP_Addr'];?>";
Guest_Num = "<?= json_encode($row['Guest_Num']);?>";
 
спс за быстрый ответ, но этот код тоже не работает.  
Проверил массив row заменив распечатав все его елементы с помощью   php.   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($newResult)) {  
      echo $row['Comments']." ".$row['IP_Addr']."          ".$row['Guest_Num']." "."<br>";    
      }   
 Все работает все записи на месте. Но когда вставляю внутрь php цикла   while(){js code ;} то выводит только 2 записи первую и последнюю..

Comment: это не внутри цикла.

Answer (score 2):

Вы меня конечно извините, но код ужасен! 
Хотя бы создайте метод, который бы принимал параметры необходимые для JS и делал echo...

Практика смешивания PHP с html и JS ни к чему хорошему не приведет, учитесь разделять одно от другого.

Сгенерируйте отдельные массивы для JS:

```
$comments = array();
$ip = array();
$guestNum = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($newResult)) 
{
   $comments[] = $row['Comments'];
   $ip[] = $row['IP_Addr'];
   $guestNum[] = $row['Guest_Num'];
}

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">          
Comments = "<?= json_encode($comments) ?>";  
IP_Addr = "<?= json_encode($ip) ?>";  
Guest_Num = "<?= json_encode($guestNum) ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: +100 пудов, из-за остутствия номрального разделения кода рождаются ошибки, т.к. нормально на алгоритм посмотреть не получается